# Pie chart crashes when no data from JSON

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, charts, chart.js

I am a beginner and learning web development. In my sample project I have created Pie Chart using ChartJS. I am getting data from REST Service. Everything is working fine and pie chart is getting rendered properly. The problem is when there is null data from REST then I am getting error in Chart.js.

**Error:** 
[image]

**JSON DATA FROM REST:**
[image]

My sample project uses BackboneJS. I know the error is because there is no data coming from REST. How can I handle that so that m Pie Chart does not crash.
Below is the MODEL:

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
    var chart = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: 'SAMPLE REST URL',
        defaults: function() {
            return {
                currMonthOccAvailVac: [],
            };
        },
        fetch: function(data) {
            var d = $.Deferred();
            var self = this;
            var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                url: this.urlRoot,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data)
            });
            ajaxRequest.done(function(json) {
                var graphVar = {
                    currMonthOccAvailVac: [],
                }
                var yearSelected = (localStorage.getItem('date')).split("-")[0];
                var monthSelected =  (localStorage.getItem('date')).split("-")[1];
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    var monthYear = json[i].columnstrDate.split("/");
                    var year = monthYear[0];
                    var month = monthYear[1];
                    if(month.length == 1)
                    if(month == (monthSelected - 1) && year == yearSelected)
                    {
                        graphVar.currMonthOccAvailVac.push(json[i].columndecOccPercentage);
                        graphVar.currMonthOccAvailVac.push(json[i].columndecVacantUnitsPercentage);
                        graphVar.currMonthOccAvailVac.push(json[i].columndecUnavailableUnitsPercentage);
                    }
                }
                self.set({
                    currMonthOccAvailVac: graphVar.currMonthOccAvailVac,

                });
                d.resolve();
            });
            //failure callback for ajax request.
            ajaxRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, status) {
                // Handle fail request
                d.reject();
            });
            return d.promise();
        }
    });
    // returning the model
    return {
        chart: chart
    };
});
```

**Place in ChartJS where actually code is breaking:**

[image]

So how can I make sure even if `graphvar.currMonthOccAvailVac` has no value the pie chart does not crash. Kindly guide me.

**EDIT**

Currently in my View Model I did something like below. But I am not sure if this the right way to handle.

```js
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
  var sixthSubViewModel = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#myChart6-template').html()),
    render: function() {
      $(this.el).html(this.template());
      var ctx = this.$el.find('#pieChart')[0];
      var data = {
        datasets: [{
          data: this.model.attributes.currMonthOccAvailVac,
          label: 'My dataset' // for legend
        }],
        labels: [
          "Rented",
          "Vacant",
          "Unavailable",
        ]
      };
      // I AM CHECKING HERE THE LENGTH AND THE RNEDERING THE PIE CHART
      if (this.model.attributes.currMonthOccAvailVac.length > 1)
        var pieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'pie',
          data: data,
          otpions: {
            legend: false
          }
        });
      WHAT SHALL I PUT IN THE ELSE PART
    },
    initialize: function() {
      this.render();
    }
  });
  return sixthSubViewModel;
});
```

Comment: Why are you asking us what shall you do when there is no data? Isn't that up to you to decide? Maybe display an error message? That's not really a programming question... BTW you should transform the response inside models `parse` method, not the `fetch`. Also instead of sending custom AJAX request you can simply manipulate the options and delegate to original sync method...

Comment: I might not have asked the question properly. What I meant to ask is why my code is crashing. Ideally an empty space should have been rendered with legends still showing. But code crashes. So I expected the pie area to be empty and legends to still show up.

Comment: I thought pie chart to be smart enough to see if no data is coming then just handle it gracefully. Just saying.

Comment: Currently, in the `Else` part I hardcoded the data as `data: [0,0,0]` and I get what I am expecting. And empty area. But I dont know if this is how I should handle it.